# How to rewrite the iteration without a nested one?

Tags: java, java-stream

Here are my iterations, but one of them is nested:

```
        objects.forEach(obj -> {
            if (obj.getType() == Type.APPLICATION) {
                clientApplicationPriorities.add(getClientApplicationPriority(obj.getApplicationShortInfo().getId(), clientId, priority, null));
            } else if (obj.getType() == Type.FOLDER) {
                final FoldersShortInfo folderInfo = obj.getFolderShortInfo();
                final String folderName = folderInfo.getName();
                final List<ApplicationShortInfo> appInfos = folderInfo.getApplications();
                appInfos.forEach(appInfo -> clientApplicationPriorities.add(getClientApplicationPriority(appInfo.getId(), clientId, priority, folderName)));
            } else {
                throw new FolderRequestException();
            }
        });
```

How can I rewrite it using Stream API?

Comment: add some more details so that a person can test and suggest

Comment: I assume you want to get rid of the inner `appInfos.forEach()`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please share some more logic related to the implementation of your code.
2. you should use switch case rather than if-elseif-else loop for more clean code.

   ```
   List<Employee> objects = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (Employee emp : objects) {
   switch (emp.getType()) { 
    case Type.application: {
           clientApplicationPriorities.add(
                   getClientApplicationPriority(obj.getApplicationShortInfo().getId(), clientId, priority, null));
       }
       case Type.folder: {
           final FoldersShortInfo folderInfo = obj.getFolderShortInfo();
           final String folderName = folderInfo.getName();
           final List<ApplicationShortInfo> appInfos = folderInfo.getApplications();
           appInfos.forEach(appInfo -> clientApplicationPriorities
                   .add(getClientApplicationPriority(appInfo.getId(), clientId, priority, folderName)));
       }
       default: {
           throw new FolderRequestException();
       }
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: There is no "need" for a switch. Its good practice, yes, but its not "needed". Also, you aren't answering the question.

Comment: yes. I have added the comment to add more details. Also, it makes code clean and easy to understand so I suggested to use switch.